# Save file from a website with java

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to build a [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) based java app to automatically download English subtitles for films (I'm lazy, I know. It was *inspired* from a similar [python](https://www.python.org/) based app). It's supposed to ask you the name of the film and then download an English subtitle for it from [subscene](http://subscene.com/).

I can make it reach the download link but I get an **Unhandled content type** error when I try to 'go' to that link. Here's my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
           String videoName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title: ");
         subscene(videoName);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
}

public static void subscene(String videoName){
       try {
           String siteName = "http://www.subscene.com";
           String[] splits = videoName.split("\\s+");
           String codeName = "";
           String text = "";
           if(splits.length>1){
               for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++){
                   codeName = codeName+splits[i]+"-";
               }
               videoName = codeName.substring(0, videoName.length());
           }
           System.out.println("videoName is "+videoName);
          // String url = "http://www.subscene.com/subtitles/"+videoName+"/english";
           String url = "http://www.subscene.com/subtitles/title?q="+videoName+"&l=";
           System.out.println("url is "+url);
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
           Element exact = doc.select("h2.exact").first();
           Element yuel = exact.nextElementSibling();
           Elements lis = yuel.children();

               System.out.println(lis.first().children().text());
               String hRef = lis.select("div.title > a").attr("href");
               hRef = siteName+hRef+"/english";

           System.out.println("hRef is "+hRef);
           doc = Jsoup.connect(hRef).get();

           Element nonHI = doc.select("td.a40").first();
           Element papa = nonHI.parent();
           Element link = papa.select("a").first();
           text = link.text();
           System.out.println("Subtitle is "+text);
           hRef = link.attr("href");
           hRef = siteName+hRef;

           Document subDownloadPage = Jsoup.connect(hRef).get();
           hRef = siteName+subDownloadPage.select("a#downloadButton").attr("href");
           Jsoup.connect(hRef).get(); //<-- Here's where the problem lies

           }
           catch (java.io.IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
   }
```

Can someone please help me so I don't have to manually download subs?

I just found out that using

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(hRef));
```

instead of

```
Jsoup.connect(hRef).get();
```

downloads the file after prompting me to save it. But I don't want to be prompted because this way I won't be able to read the name of the downloaded zip file (I want to unzip it after saving using java).

Comment: Could you provide more details on the exception?

Comment: It says **Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml**

Comment: what is being printed out with `System.out.println("hRef is "+hRef);`

Comment: Scary Wombat http:// www.subscene.com/subtitles/memento-2000/english

Comment: Down voter please tell me why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Document subDownloadPage = Jsoup.connect(hRef).get();
hRef = siteName+subDownloadPage.select("a#downloadButton").attr("href");
//specifically here
Jsoup.connect(hRef).get();
```

Looks like jsoup expects that the result of `Jsoup.connect(hRef)` should be an HTML or some text that it's able to parse, that's why the message states:

> Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml

I followed the execution of your code manually and the last URL you're trying to access returns a content type of `application/x-zip-compressed`, thus the cause of the exception.

In order to download this file, you should use a different approach. You could use the old but still useful [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) or use a third party library like Apache HttpComponents to fire a GET request and retrieve the result as an `InputStream`, wrap it into a proper writer and write your file into your disk.

Here's an example about doing this using `URL`:

```
URL url = new URL(hRef);
InputStream in = url.openStream();
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\foo.zip"));
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
int length;
while ( (length = bis.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: @Amber you're welcome. I've updated the code in order to be way more efficient. Please use this code rather than the old code provided before.

Comment: You should just tell JSoup to ignore the contentType. (see my answer) Your buffer size is 4KB in size, and most srt files are only about 100KB. So, the impact in memory usage is small. Is it worth the uglyness of your code? You could do the same thing in 2 lines.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your files are small, you can do it like this. Note that you can tell Jsoup to ignore the content type.

```
// get the file content
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(path);
connection.timeout(5000);
Connection.Response resultImageResponse = connection.ignoreContentType(true).execute();

// save to file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
out.close();
```

I would recommend to verify the content before saving.
Because some servers will just return a HTML page when the file cannot be found, i.e. a broken hyperlink.

```
...
String body = resultImageResponse.body();
if (body == null || body.toLowerCase().contains("<body>"))
{
  throw new IllegalStateException("invalid file content");
}
...
```

Comment: The approach is good, but I don't recommend using this: `out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());`. It is **way better** to read parts of the file in small chunks of 4 or 8 KBs as shown in my answer. Probably you cannot see the *issue* since those are very small files, bu it is when you work with huge files, specially over a network e.g. file upload/download.

Comment: As I said : "Assuming that your files ares small" , which is the case here. Subtitle files are small files. So, I think this is more readable.